# Limiting resource use per user with cgroups/systemd

Tags: systemd, cgroup, debian-buster

Debian 10: I want to limit memory, CPU etc for all users except `root`; I have found several articles about this, but so far they all revolve around cgconfig, which doesn't seem to be the way it is done now. I have seen some suggestions to use slices instead, so for UID 1000, create something like:

```
# cat /lib/systemd/system/user-1000.slice
[Unit]
Description=User and Session Slice
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Before=slices.target
MemoryHigh=20M

[Slice]
Slice=user-slice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and enable it with `systemctl enable user-1000.slice`. This appears to half work:

```
 $ systemctl status user-1000.slice
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of user-1000.slice changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● user-1000.slice - User Slice of UID 1000
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user-1000.slice; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/user-.slice.d
           └─10-defaults.conf
   Active: active since Thu 2020-07-09 07:37:28 UTC; 1h 8min ago
     Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
           man:user@.service(5)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 5237)
   Memory: 5.4M
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice
           ├─session-15.scope
           │ ├─1089 sshd: jan [priv]
           │ ├─1107 sshd: jan@pts/1
           │ ├─1108 -bash
           │ ├─1113 systemctl status user-1000.slice
           │ └─1114 pager
           └─user@1000.service
             └─init.scope
               ├─1092 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
               └─1093 (sd-pam)
```

However, `MemoryHigh` isn't set:

```
 $ systemctl show user-1000.slice
Slice=user.slice
ControlGroup=/user.slice/user-1000.slice
...
MemoryHigh=infinity
...
```

I seem to be very close, but there must be something missing - what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the warning that was printed on screen:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of user-1000.slice changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
```

When you change systemd units, you must `systemctl daemon-reload` to have systemd re-read them. In addition, affected units need to be restarted.

That said, if you want the change to apply to all users, you should probably be overriding `user.slice` instead. And of course you should never edit the system-shipped files, but instead use overrides via [drop-in files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398540/20805).

Comment: You were right! Thx